# How to add colSpan in ReactJS styled components?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, html-table

I am making a small web application to display as and HTML table a **JSON dataset** which has different events. I am using styled-components library to add CSS to my components. The thing is that I am trying to get a table like this one:

[image: How I would like to be]

The thing is that what I am obtaining is this table:

[image: Obtained table]

The CSS used:

```
  const TableHeader = styled.th`
    border-color: black;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    font-family:Arial; sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:normal;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:10px 5px;
    word-break:normal;
  `;
```

The ReacJS-HTML used:

```
<TableHeader>{props.id}</TableHeader>
```

How can I add to this ReactJS styled-components which is the table header where the ID is displayed to have a colSpan={2}?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try like this

```
const TableHeader = styled.th.attrs({
  colSpan: 2
})`
    border-color: black;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    font-family:Arial; sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:normal;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:10px 5px;
    word-break:normal;
  `;
```

Comment: For React, the column span number *may* need to be specified as a string, i.e. `colSpan: "2",`. For this answer please also try to explain what `.attrs` is and *why* it resolves the issue.

Comment: Please check their document here; https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#attaching-additional-props

Comment: Thank you so much! I checked the docs, but I didn't know how to apply it for the colSpan attribute. Again, thank you so much.